# Zend Form Element Regex Validator seems to deny value when 0

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form-element, zend-validate

Today, I have come across a bug in my Zend Framework application. This is the case:

I have a form with an element that has a regex validator on it. When testing the form, I found out that I can not provide the value 0 for the element. Zend gives me an error, telling me that I have not filled in the element.

The element:

```
$element = $this->createElement( "text", "amount", array( "label" => "Amount", "required" => true ) );
$element->addValidator( 'regex', false, array( '/^[-]?([0-9]+)(([,.][0-9]+)+)?$/' ) );
```

Can anyone tell me what the reason might be that Zend tells me I have not filled in the element when the submitted value is 0?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very simple, when you set "required" as `true`, Zend_Form_Element automatically adds a [notEmpty()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.notempty) validator at the top of the validators stack.

Therefore, any **null, 0, "", etc.** values are considered `false`, and this validator set an error to your form.

See the manual for more information:

> ### Default behaviour for Zend_Validate_NotEmpty
>
> By default, this validator works differently than you would expect when you've worked
>   with PHP's empty() function. In particular, this validator will
>   evaluate both the integer 0 and string '0' as empty.

```
$valid = new Zend_Validate_NotEmpty();
$value  = '';
$result = $valid->isValid($value);
// returns false
```